# Python trying to make Cookie Clicker where upgrade adds to number every second

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is where it will have multiple buttons where you can upgrade to earn more ore such as having something that doubles ore count per click or where it adds 1 to counter every second etc.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("Pascal Mining Company")
root.geometry("400x200")

global ore
ore = 0

def nClick():

    global ore
    ore += 1
    OreLabel.config(text=ore)

#This is where I want to add 1 to ore every second when this click this button
# I already have it where it subtracts the 100 as the price of the upgrade

def upgrade():

    global ore
    if ore >= 100:
        ore -= 100
        OreLabel.config(text=ore)

OreLabel = Label(root, text=ore)
b1 = Button(root, text="Mine", command=nClick)
b2 = Button(root, text="Upgrade Miner", command=upgrade)
b3 = Button(root, text="Jack Hammer")

OreLabel.pack()
b3.pack()
b2.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `root.after(1000, function_name_without_parenthesis)` to run function after 1000ms (1second). Inside this function you can use another `root.after(1000, the_same_function_name)`

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What problem are you having?

Comment: But how would I use it to always keep adding 1 to it after i click the button. I am asking what would I do to when I click the button so it will add 1 to a counter

Comment: Oh I got it it worked